# How to do deep learning through python weka wrapper3?

Tags: python, deep-learning, weka

I am doing a experiment,it is a question about classification,for example,I got the train dataset and test dataset.Every instance has 12 different attributes(id name......) and 1 class (Value = True or False),the train dataset has told us the class value of all instances,test dataset doesn't.It seems that my task is to construct a classifier, can I just use the Classifiers in the Python weka wrapper3,such as the Random forest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RandomForest =/= deep learning

With [python-weka-wrapper3](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper3) you can use any classifier available in Weka (e.g., through the Weka Explorer). All you have to do is copy the command-line from the Weka Explorer via right-click and instantiate your `Classifier` object from it:

```py
import weka.core.jvm as jvm
from weka.core.classes import from_commandline

jvm.start(packages=True)

# commandline obtained from Weka Explorer via right-click menu
cmdline = "weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest -P 100 -I 100 -num-slots 1 -K 0 -M 1.0 -V 0.001 -S 1"

# instantiate Classifier object from commandline
cls = from_commandline(cmdline, classname="weka.classifiers.Classifier")

# output commandline again to confirm its correct
print(cls.to_commandline())

jvm.stop()
```

At the time of writing, this should be output:

```
weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest -P 100 -I 100 -num-slots 1 -K 0 -M 1.0 -V 0.001 -S 1
```

Comment: thankes，I got that